# What is the best way to extract a zip file using java

Tags: java, compression

I have a a zipped file. That file contains various directories and files also. I want to extract all those and save in a specified path.

So How to write a java program to extract the zipped file.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unzip files recursively in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981578/how-to-unzip-files-recursively-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static  void unzip(){
      try{
           BufferedOutputStream out = null;
           ZipInputStream  in = new ZipInputStream(ZipFileExtracter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/artificialmachines/chitme/stamps/ChitMeData.zip"));
           ZipEntry entry;
           boolean isDirectory=false;
           while((entry = in.getNextEntry()) != null){
               int count;
               byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
               // write the files to the disk
               String entryName = entry.getName();
               File newFile = new File(new StringBuffer().append(System.getProperty("user.dir")).append(File.separator).append(entryName).toString());
               if(entryName.endsWith("/")){
                   isDirectory=true;
                   newFile.mkdir();
                   //System.out.println("This is directory "+newFile.exists()+"  IS DIr "+newFile.isDirectory()+"    path "+newFile.getPath());
               }else{
                   newFile.createNewFile();
               }
               if(!isDirectory){
                   out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile),BUFFER);
                    while ((count = in.read(data,0,BUFFER)) != -1){
                         out.write(data,0,count);
                    }
                    cleanUp(out);
               }
               isDirectory=false;
           }
           cleanUp(in);
      }
      catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.exit(0);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look into using the [`java.util.zip` package](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html).  Sun provides a tutorial on how to use it: [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/).

Answer (score 1):

java.util.zip.* does the required thing.
Go through the API for refernec. If you are looking for example [LookThis](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util.zip/how-to-extract-file-files-from-a-zip-file-3.html)