# FileNotFoundException when trying to unzip an archive with java.util.zip.ZipFile

Tags: java, unzip, filenotfoundexception

I have a silly problem i haven't been able to figure out. Can anyone help me?
My Code is as:

```
String zipname = "C:/1100.zip";
    String output = "C:/1100";
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipname);
        Enumeration<?> enumeration = zipFile.entries();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Unzipping: " + zipEntry.getName());
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry));
            int size;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
```

It doesn't create a folder but debugging shows all the contents being generated.
In Order to create a folder i used the code

> `if(!output.exists()){ output.mkdir();} // here i get an error saying filenotfoundexception`

```
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outPut)));
            while ((size = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        bis.close();
    }
```

My zip file contains images: a.jpg b.jpg... and in the same hierarchy, I have abc.xml.
I need to extract the content as is in the zip file.
Any helps here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code: Where is outPut declared? `output` is not a file but a string, so `exists()` and `mkdir()` do not exist. Start by declaring `output` like:

```
File output = new File("C:/1100");
```

Furthermore, `outPut` (with big P) is not declared. It be something like `output + File.seprator + zipEntry.getName()`.

```
 bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output + File.seprator + zipEntry.getName()));
```

Note that you don't need to pass a File to FileOutputStream, as constructors show in [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

At this point, your code should work if your Zip file does not contain directory. However, when opening the output stream, if zipEntry.getName() has a directory component (for instance `somedir/filename.txt`), opening the stream will result in a `FileNotFoundException`, as the parent directory of the file you try to create does not exist. If you want to be able to handle such zip files, you will find your answer in: [How to unzip files recursively in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981578/how-to-unzip-files-recursively-in-java)

Comment: Finally i wrote it for my blog: http://thaparobin.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-unpack-zip-file-from-remote-url.html