# Get contents of a directory in a ZIP file in Java

Tags: java, jar, zip

I have some default configuration files inside my application jar that I would like to save to the file system if they don't already exist. I would like it to keep the directory structure too. Example:

```
Jar file
-configs/
    -main-config.cfg
    -another-file.txt
    -stuff/
        -another-file.cfg
-com/
-META-INF/
```

I would like the contents of configs/ to be mirrored to the file system, including the subfolder.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981578/how-to-unzip-files-recursively-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JarFile.entries`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#entries%28%29) to get an enumeration of all of the entries in your Jar file.

Comment: How would I check that they are in the directory I want, etc? I've barely used the zip/jar packages before.

Comment: @SeanGordon You can get the [name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getName()) of the entry and see if it [begins](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) with the directory you want.