# Java code to extract all files from a jar to a given location

Tags: java

I want to copy all files inside jar file to outside the current directory.

Here is my code. It's writing all files name inside jar, so.. But I want to copy all the files from inside the jar to outside the jar.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

   public class JarRead 
   {
     public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException 
     {
         ZipFile file = new ZipFile("jarfile.jar");
         if (file != null) {
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = file.entries(); 

            if (entries != null) {
               while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                   ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                   System.out.println(entry);

               }
             }
         }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please use the edit link to clean up the multiple use of "..".

Comment: You can get an `InputStream` by calling `file.getInputStream(entry)`.

Comment: what you said, sorry, i didn't understand!! Please help me thanks!!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981578/how-to-unzip-files-recursively-in-java

Comment: please help me guys, how i can do that?? please.. THanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write a Java program to do this. You could use a shell script. You could just `unzip` the jar file, and then `find` the files in the directory and `mv` them into the directory you have.

Comment: That's not the point. He wants to do it in Java, not a shell script. -1

Comment: Well, i know, I can do without java program.. I want java program to do this acutally :) please help me thanks!!

Comment: OP specifies he doesn't need to use Java. +1 for balance

Comment: The unzip executable is an extra dependency the system may not have.

Comment: My apologies; I read "I want to copy all the files from inside the jar to outside the jar." and thought that the goal was what you were actually interested in, and not the code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that does this. You probably have to modify it a little.

```
public class HtDocsExtractor {
    private final String htDocsPath;

    public HtDocsExtractor(String htDocsPath) {
        this.htDocsPath = htDocsPath;
    }

    public void extract() throws Exception {

        InputStream is = HtDocsExtractor.class.getResourceAsStream("/htdocs.zip");
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            ZipEntry zipentry;

            zipentry = zis.getNextEntry();
            while (zipentry != null) {
                String entryName = htDocsPath + zipentry.getName();
                entryName = entryName.replace('/', File.separatorChar);
                entryName = entryName.replace('\\', File.separatorChar);
                int n;
                File newFile = new File(entryName);
                if (zipentry.isDirectory()) {
                    if (!newFile.exists() && !newFile.mkdirs()) {
                        throw new Exception("Could not create directory: " + newFile);
                    }
                    zipentry = zis.getNextEntry();
                }
                else {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entryName);
                    try {
                        while ((n = zis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            fos.write(buf, 0, n);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        fos.close();
                    }
                    zis.closeEntry();
                    zipentry = zis.getNextEntry();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            zis.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is hard way to do it.. i need understand program.. acutally.. how its work?? If i changed file name htdocs.zip to my file name it should work right