# How to recursively unpack archives of type war/ear/pack.gz/tar.gz

Tags: java, shell, recursion, archive

is there a easy and simple way to recursively unpack nested archives of the type war/ear/pack.gz/tar.gz, so a directory tree is created - so also for ears in wars and so on?

I don't care if it is in a standard shell or java as afterwards I have to continue processing the files inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip files recursively in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981578/how-to-unzip-files-recursively-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You may find [rjar](https://github.com/pojosontheweb/rjar) helpful, from the documentation:

> `rjar` is a command-line tool that acts like the regular `jar` tool, but *recursively* ! It is very useful when e.g. using .ear or .war files, or any other "jars of jars"...
>
> Also works zith .zip files !
>
> Supported features :
>
> - *list jar entries recursively* : all entries are displayed including entries of nested jars if any
> - *expand a jar recursively* : expand the jar and its nested jars to the specified directory
> - *recreate a jar from an expanded rjar* : allows to rebuild a jar with nested jars from an expanded directory structure
> - *graphical front-end* : tree view of your jars, with regexp filtering